# How do I append a crc16 value to the end of a char array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, crc16

I have some data that needs to be sent as a string along with a crc16 value. The format is like this:
",,,...,crc16\r"
I have a crc16 function that I pass the data into as a character array, and the crc result is returned as an unsigned short. I am having trouble figuring out how to append the crc value to the string since it has a different data type from the rest of the string.

I thought I might need to convert the crc to 2 ascii characters. Not sure how to do that though

Comment: Use `snprintf`.

Comment: It depends on whether the final string needs to be printable text. If not then you simply split the crc into two bytes using shifting and masking. But if it needs to be printable ASCII, then your choices are three characters using [base 64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), or four characters using hexadecimal.

Answer (score 2):

I'll make few guesses here:

- Your CRC value should be appended to your ascii string *as ascii string as well*, likely in hexadecimal representation.

Here is a simple code to copy the string and append it with the calculated CRC value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    uint16_t crc = 0xBEEF;
    char message[] = "Blah blah.";
    char output[100]; // Make sure it has enough space for both, 
                      //the string and the CRC (and the null terminator).
    
    sprintf(output, "%s,%04X\r", message, crc);
    // For extra memory safety use
    // snprintf(output, sizeof output, "%s,%04X\r", message, crc);
    
    printf("%s\n", output);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Depending on the requirements, you might need to swap the bytes of CRC..

[Demo](https://ideone.com/Ztuk6d)

Answer (score 0):

Break the CRC into two bytes. `unsigned high = crc >> 8, low = crc & 0xff;`. Then insert them directly in the string by offset, e.g. `str[17] = low; str[18] = high;` (whatever the correct indices are), or if you are using `printf()` to make the string, then something like `printf("... %c%c\r", ..., low, high);`.

Comment: I am pretty sure that CRC should come as ASCII string as well (likely in Hex). Similarly to GPS NMEA protocol.